# Shell script - why can't I convert merged CSV to JSON?

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, csv

I have a shell script that holds a variable array of URL's (two at the moment, once it's working I'll add more), I can get my program to convert individual CSV files related to the url crawled e.g. www.example.com would turn out as 2014-10-28-example.csv and it would convert no problem, but if I append the rest of the csv(s) that were created that day it will not convert the file into JSON, an if I merge them into a new file it will not convert it. Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 311, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 298, in main
    mySite=Site(csvFilePath)
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.buildPageData(csvFilePath)
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 156, in buildPageData
    self.pageData[pageURL]["Title"]=self.cleanTitle(line[1],pageURL)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The freshmaps file converts the csv to JSON, here is the section it is getting caught on:

```
    def __init__(self,csvFilePath):
    global dateofCrawl
    dateOfCrawl = 0;
    self.pageList = [] # ordered list of page IDs
    self.pageData={} # dictionary of individual page dictionaries, indexed on page ID
    self.titleDict = { } # dictionary of unique titles
    self.buildPageData(csvFilePath)
    self.homePageId=self.pageList[0] # only use of site.pageList
    self.depth=0

def buildPageData(self,csvFilePath):
    global dateOfCrawl
    # read data from CSV file, build a dictionary of page data, including list of children, in order
    lines = csv.reader(open(csvFilePath, "rb"))
    for line in lines:
        pageURL=line[0]
        pageURL=re.sub('\/\Z', '',pageURL) # remove any trailing slash
        self.pageData[pageURL]={}
        self.pageData[pageURL]["URL"]=pageURL
        self.pageData[pageURL]["Title"]=self.cleanTitle(line[1],pageURL)()
```

The image below gives a sample of the output when the two files are merged, what would be an appropriate solution to either correct the columns or edit cell content?

[CSV Data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55866446/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-29%20at%2021.45.53.png)

Comment: This error `self.pageData[pageURL]["Modified"]=line[2]
IndexError: list index out of range` means that `line` does not have a second field. What is the line in question?

Comment: @EtanReisner, ...you mean a third field; python lists are zero-indexed.

Comment: ...on a different topic -- WTF? You're using Python; the Python standard library includes a proper JSON generation library; why in the world would you try to roll your own? There's no reason to believe that `'"' + str(x) + '"'` is going to be the proper way to encode `x` for JSON (which has its own quoting, escaping, and character-encoding rules), and in a great many cases it flat-out **isn't**.

Comment: Also, `for var3 in "${var3[@]}"` overwrites your array with the items extracted from it, and the lack of quoting all over the shell parts is a source of constant uncertainty (as if your data includes whitespace or wildcard characters, there's going to be fun to be had around string-splitting and glob expansion).

Comment: I'd strongly recommend running all this through http://shellcheck.net/, fixing the errors that static analysis comes up with, and _isolating a single problem_ before asking here at StackOverflow. There are so many things that are slightly broken throughout this code that we can't reasonably help as it is.

Comment: Shall do that just now, the reason for using this format is it is meant to be treemap of websites, so users can enter www.example.com and it will show all its children and how old that page is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think the issue is that when the CSV files are merged, some of the information overlaps columns i.e. date would be where another/separate system's unique page ID would be, there are no column headers when the files are generated, do you know of a way to edit individual cells without doing it manually?

Comment: @Alex6534, if you can narrow that question down to something you can build a SSCCE / MVCE for (roughly, a standalone reproducer with absolutely no code extraneous to the question at hand), do that, and ask it as a separate question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Alex6534, ...right now, you've showed nobody any data, so when you talk about page IDs and column headers, we don't know what you're talking about. With a SSCCE, everything we need to know to answer the question, **including data**, would (necessarily) be part of the code demonstrating the question -- hence, "self-contained".

Comment: There's a quote from The Mythical Man Month that's apropos here: "Show me your flowcharts and conceal your tables, and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your tables, and I won’t usually need your flowcharts; they’ll be obvious."

Comment: Point taken @CharlesDuffy, I have edited the question and included only the lines that are referenced in traceback and an image of the merged data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Found an easier solution of merging json data and removing objects from the JSON file rather than merging CSV's.